# Android Pie (9.0) WebView in multi-process

Tags: android, multiprocessing, android-service, android-9.0-pie

Starting Android Pie (API 28), Google isn't allowing using a single WebView instance in 2 different processes.

Documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setDataDirectorySuffix(java.lang.String)

As required, I called `WebView.setDataDirectorySuffix("dir_name_no_separator")` but unfortunately, I get an exception.
I tried to call this method inside the 2nd process Service onCreate().

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.myapp.service.MyService: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't set data directory suffix: WebView already initialized
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3544)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1666)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't set data directory suffix: WebView already initialized
        at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.setDataDirectorySuffix(WebViewFactory.java:136)
        at android.webkit.WebView.setDataDirectorySuffix(WebView.java:2165)
        at com.myapp.service.MyService.onCreate(MyService.java:134)
```

I couldn't find any reason for that exception. I didn't call this method twice nor I called it in my main process. Any ideas?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Solved.

My project hosts AdMob ads and I call the `MobileAds.initialize()` method inside my `Application` class `onCreate()`. The ads initializer loads a `WebView` which is now forbidden to do in a new process before you call the `WebView.setDataDirectorySuffix("dir_name_no_separator")` method.

When the second process is created, it also goes through the same application create flow, meaning it calls the same `onCreate()` inside the `Application` class, which calls the  `MobileAds.initialize()` that tries to create a new `WebView` instance and by that causes the crash.

```
IllegalStateException: Can't set data directory suffix: WebView already initialized
```

**How I solved this?**

I get the process name using the below method and check if it's my main process - call the MobileAds.initialize() method and if it's my second process, call the 
`WebView.setDataDirectorySuffix("dir_name_no_separator")` method.

Get process name:

```
public static String getProcessName(Context context) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : manager.getRunningAppProcesses()) {
        if (processInfo.pid == android.os.Process.myPid()) {
            return processInfo.processName;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Application class onCreate():

```
if (!Utils.getProcessName(this).equals("YOUR_SECOND_PROCESS_NAME")) {
    MobileAds.initialize(this);
} else {
    WebView.setDataDirectorySuffix("dir_name_no_separator")
}
```

Comment: lluz i am facing similar problem but with different exception do you know anything about it? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52144354/admob-banner-ad-not-loading-in-android-p?noredirect=1#comment91240321_52144354)

Comment: This is a little modification: 

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            String process = getProcessName(this);
            if (!getPackageName().equals(process)) WebView.setDataDirectorySuffix(process);
        }

Comment: API 28 onwards there is a new api to get process name which is more performant. Check out https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#getProcessName()

Comment: What is "YOUR_SECOND_PROCESS_NAME" here?

Comment: @DarShan your second process name,  as you named it on the Manifest but as you can read in comments above - there's a better API to get the process name so I advise using it instead.

Comment: I figured that out and used the above code in my code, however now the webview can’t load the javascript, you have any idea on that??

Comment: What if I don't have "process" anywhere in the manifest, and yet I see this issue? I've tried searching "process" in the merged manifest (after creating the APK), and didn't find it. Instead I've found 2 entries with `multiprocess` for 2 providers, but I don't think this could cause it, right?

Comment: @androiddeveloper don't think so. Do you (or any SDK you use) instantiate different WebViews on your application class? Check if you do that more than once on runtime.

Comment: @LiorIluz Might be. There are normal ones, and there are of ads. There might be more too. Why does it matter?

Comment: @androiddeveloper did you try adding my code and see if it helps? Only add if (myProcess) { WebView.setDataDirectorySuffix() } . no else. {}

Comment: I don't understand. I added the next code, but the app isn't published yet: 
`val processName = Application.getProcessName();
if (context.packageName != processName)
    WebView.setDataDirectorySuffix(processName)` . Sorry for the formatting here. Hope you can read what's written.

Comment: @androiddeveloper why do you compare package to process name? You should compare your process name... just in case your app has another process that is being initialised somehow. I'm not saying it is but this is the only reason I know this crash can occur and a simple if condition can solve.

Comment: The package name is the default name of the process, unless you've changed it in manifest, no?

Comment: @androiddeveloper not sure, don't remember actually, did it a while ago :) If it is and you make sure to call this method only on your process and it's still crashing, I have no idea why unfortunately.

Comment: It'd be great if you provide concrete variables with calculated values, instead of placeholders like "YOUR_SECOND_PROCESS_NAME" or "dir_name_no_separator" which are difficult to understand to the reader. Thanks for the answer anyway

Answer (score 5):

To summarize the fix with all the improvements, this is the code in Kotlin:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    if (packageName != Application.getProcessName()) {
        WebView.setDataDirectorySuffix(Application.getProcessName())
    }
}
```

Add it to your `Application` class to `onCreate()` method.

Note this is will only fix problem with maximum 2 processes. If your app is using more, you have to provide different WebView suffix for each of them.

Comment: What should be "processName" ?

Comment: should be "getProcessName()", I've updated the answer

Comment: I see. Do you know perhaps of other cases this issue can occur ? I've tried searching "process" in the merged manifest (after creating the APK), and didn't find it. Instead I've found 2 entries with multiprocess for 2 providers, but I don't think this could cause it, right?

Comment: @androiddeveloper I don't know about any other case right now, after applying this fix I don't see the exception anymore. But if you find something, share it here pls. :-)

Comment: I hope it will fix it. I have no idea why it occurs. Will take some time to decide if it helps or not. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

when error due to ads, then in application class

```
try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            val process = getProcessName()
            if (packageName != process) WebView.setDataDirectorySuffix(process)
        }

        MobileAds.initialize(this)
        AudienceNetworkAds.initialize(this)

    } catch (e: Error) {
        Timber.e(e)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Timber.e(e)
    }
```

Comment: Is this still an issue nowadays ? If not, from which version?

Comment: In 2020 I added this code to remove crash, after it I not checked by removing it

Comment: Do you remember, perhaps, if it occurred after Android P ?

Comment: yes this occur on P and after it, when our app opens from launcher icon and also from file manager, means two or more instances of our app created!

Comment: I see. Do you remember what's the max version that you've noticed it happening ? And how do you know so much details? You've reproduced it yourself?