# Admob ad stopped working in Android pie API28

Tags: android, admob

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52144354/admob-banner-ad-not-loading-in-android-p) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51843546/android-pie-9-0-webview-in-multi-process) but I am not using multiple WebViews. Also, my account is not new and ads are showing in other lower versions of Android.

```
W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
```

Comment: Anyway please try this way):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51843546/android-pie-9-0-webview-in-multi-process

Comment: @HovanesMosoyan Have you even read my question? I already said I tried this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearing google play services cache and data seems to fix this for me but it does come back after redeploying an apk to my device in either debug mode or not debug mode using Android Studio.

Not really happy about having to clear play services data.  Blew away my BT connection to my Wear OS watch which may require a factory reset on the watch to re-pair!

Comment: I don't have to clear anything it started showing today on its own.

Comment: Good.  My issue came back again yesterday after clearing cache but then I too noticed test ads were working reliably again today.

Comment: Honestly I just weird. I hope it doesn't suffer in production.