# Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException:Using WebView from more than one process at once with the same data directory is not supported

Tags: android, webview, process

1.When I in Fragment onCreateView method inflater.inflate(webview_layout, container, false) on Android 9  may Crash with blow log:

```
    Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException:Using WebView from more than one process at once with the same data directory is not supported. https://crbug.com/558377
    at jO.b(PG:102)
    at jQ.run(PG:3)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7210)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:499)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:961)
```

2.I try add blow code in Application onCreate method

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    String processName = getProcessName();
    if (!MAIN_PROCESS.equals(processName)) {
        WebView.setDataDirectorySuffix(getProcessName() + ".webview");
    }
}
```

but some Android mobile phone alse Crash with same reason,and I don't use webview with multi process, then I try add this code in Fragment onCreateView before inflater.inflate(webview_layout, container, false)

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    String processName = getProcessName();
    try {
        WebView.setDataDirectorySuffix(processName);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // ignore
    }
}
```

But I also get some the same crash report in PCAM10\PCEM00\PCAT10...  and I can't reappear this crash local.

Is also some other reason with this Crash?

Comment: Getting same error in some of device.

Comment: Any update about this case?

Answer (score 12):

using this code in Application class before initializing Admob solve my problem:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        val process = getProcessName()
        if (packageName != process) WebView.setDataDirectorySuffix(process)
    }

MobileAds.initialize(this)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a new effective API to get process name for API 28 onwards.
[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#getProcessName()][1]

As mentioned in google documentation, from API 28, it's clear that WebView running in multiprocess can not share the same data directory.

> This means that different processes in the same application cannot
> directly share WebView-related data, since the data directories must
> be distinct.

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setDataDirectorySuffix(java.lang.String)
- https://arjun30.medium.com/webview-data-directory-for-android-9-pie-d9744a1404e9

Another thing, please check if you are initializing any process in the Application class or not.
Reference link :
[Android Pie (9.0) WebView in multi-process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51843546/android-pie-9-0-webview-in-multi-process)

Answer (score 1):

If you have two or more different processes for your app and services then you could just disable WebView usage in the process which doesnt intend to use WebView [WebView.disableWebView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#disableWebView())

```
public void onCreate() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        WebView.disableWebView();
    }
    ...
}
```

In that case exception will be thrown if a WebView is created or any other methods in the android.webkit package are used by process. But the "java.lang.RuntimeException:Using WebView from more than one process...." exception will gone