# Using WebView from more than one process at once with the same data directory is not supported in Samsung Gallaxy Note version 9

Tags: java, android, webview, android-9.0-pie

How can I check this? In my app, I didn't set any webviewdirectory in the code?

So I went ahead and add the WebView checks as mentioned in this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62079558/fatal-exception-java-lang-runtimeexceptionusing-webview-from-more-than-one-pro`. And printed the process name and it returns the package name. Is this correct and how to resolve this?

Error;

```
   Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
    Using WebView from more than one process at once with the same data directory is not supported. 
https://crbug.com/558377 : Current process ), lock owner unknown
    org.chromium.android_webview.AwDataDirLock.b (chromium-Monochrome.aab-stable-626110521:180)
    org.chromium.android_webview.AwBrowserProcess.j (chromium-Monochrome.aab-stable-626110521:15)
    com.android.webview.chromium.M.f (chromium-Monochrome.aab-stable-626110521:163)
    c65.run (chromium-Monochrome.aab-stable-626110521:8)

android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:975)
```