# How to fix the Android AdMob "Unable to obtain a JavascriptEngine" error?

Tags: android, admob, javascript-engine

`MainActivity`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        MobileAds.initialize(this) {}
        MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(
            RequestConfiguration.Builder()
                .setTestDeviceIds(listOf("ABCDEF012345"))
                .build()
        )

        val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
        Log.d("Activity", "Is Test Device? : ${adRequest.isTestDevice(this)}")
        adView.loadAd(adRequest)

        adView.adListener = object : AdListener() {
            override fun onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded()
                Log.d("Activity", "@@ onAdLoaded()")
            }

            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(err: LoadAdError?) {
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(err)
                Log.d("Activity", "@@ onAdFailedToLoad()\n$err")
            }

            override fun onAdOpened() {
                super.onAdOpened()
                Log.d("Activity", "@@ onAdOpened()")
            }

            override fun onAdClicked() {
                super.onAdClicked()
                Log.d("Activity", "@@ onAdClicked()")
            }

            override fun onAdLeftApplication() {
                super.onAdLeftApplication()
                Log.d("Activity", "@@ onAdLeftApplication()")
            }

            override fun onAdClosed() {
                super.onAdClosed()
                Log.d("Activity", "@@ onAdClosed()")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout                       
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id_for_test" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`string.xml`

```
<resources>
    <string name="admob_app_id">ca-app-pub-000000000000~00000000000</string>
    <string name="bannera_ad_unit_id_for_test">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>
</resources>
```

I created `<meta-dat>` in the manifest and added `admob_app_id` as the `android:value` value inside. In the AVD test device provided by Android Studio, a test advertisement appeared without any problems, but the test advertisement did not appear on the actual device. So, as in the `MainActivity` code above, I called `RequestConfiguration` and added my mobile device ID(`"ABCDEF012345"`) to the test device ID, but the problem was not resolved. The contents of the error were as follows.

[image]

Comment: check the error code, it must be the error code: 0 (internal error) as mentioned here. https://support.google.com/admob/thread/3494603?hl=en

Answer (score 26):

Probably not the solution for everyone, but fixed it for me: **don't forget to turn off all kinds of adblockers**.

I had a adblocker DNS configured, took me some time to finally figure that out.

Comment: this is the correct answer, I had the same error on my rooted device with an adblocker installed (lucky patcher), when I re-enabled ads on the adblocker the error is no more.

Comment: also, this happens if you have pi-hole like me. this answer helped a lot.

Comment: also this happens when you are using manual proxy on your device connection

Comment: So what do you think the reason is if this happens for users (reported by Google Analytics). That they use ad block?

Comment: @DoronBen-Ari absolutely, either Adblock app or DNS somewhere (Could even be configured in a router they are connected to without them knowing). If it isn't affecting many users I'd just assume this is the case and ignore it.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time **AdMob** does not perform as expected on the emulator, because there was no same stuff like play store services on it. Try on a real device. Sometimes a **cold boot** on the emulator solve the problem.

1. Visit the AdMob Policy Center to view any pending violations.
2. Don't use VPN, Don't use Proxy at all.
3. Just make sure to use test ad unit ID while debugging.
4. Perform a cold boot on the emulator.
5. Use a real device instead emulator.

Comment: “Don't use Proxy at all” saves my day, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I was using manual proxy for the WIFI, ad forget to change and this strange thing happened to me was `Unable to obtain a JavascriptEngine` in `onAdFailedToLoad`, just soled by modifying the WIFI Network to Proxy>NONE in the Advance option by Long Tap on the connected WIFI

Answer (score 1):

For Russia where AdMob is blocked by Google nowdays, you otherwise should switc VPN On.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines in proguard-rule file

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.ads.** { *; }
```

Also read about Proguard and AdMob

[Proguard and AdMob mediation](https://ads-developers.googleblog.com/2015/10/proguard-and-admob-mediation.html)

Answer (score -2):

I've got a similar issue on Android when using native ads. The error information is very similar :

```
code:0 message:Unable to obtain a JavascriptEngine. domain:com.google.android.gms.ads cause:null responseInfo:{
  "Response ID": "null",
  "Mediation Adapter Class Name": "",
  "Adapter Responses": []
}
```

But, I've got a clue that might be the reason for this: As I've noticed weird crashes sometimes on the app, I've decided to add a check that indeed the app seems valid, by checking its signature.

What I've found is that in this case, at least 2 devices had the app changed (maybe by the same person). So this user for some reason tried to change the app. No idea what he tried to do with it, but I hope this could solve your problem.

If you want, here's a basic way to do it:

```
private var sIsValidInstall: Boolean? = null
private const val BYTE_SIZE_FOR_DEBUG_SIGNATURE=...
private const val CRC_FOR_DEBUG_SIGNATURE=...
private const val BYTE_SIZE_FOR_DEBUG_SIGNATURE=...
private const val CRC_FOR_DEBUG_SIGNATURE=...

@SuppressLint("PackageManagerGetSignatures")
fun isValidInstall(context: Context): Boolean {
    sIsValidInstall?.let { return it }
    var isValid = false
    val signatures = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
        context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES).signingInfo.apkContentsSigners
    else context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures
    for (signature in signatures) {
        val bytes = signature.toByteArray()
        if (bytes != null) {
            val bytesSize = bytes.size
            val checksum = CRC32()
            checksum.update(bytes, 0, bytes.size)
            val crc = checksum.value
            isValid = (BuildConfig.DEBUG && bytesSize == BYTE_SIZE_FOR_DEBUG_SIGNATURE && crc == CRC_FOR_DEBUG_SIGNATURE) || (!BuildConfig.DEBUG && bytesSize == BYTE_SIZE_FOR_DEBUG_SIGNATURE && crc == CRC_FOR_DEBUG_SIGNATURE)
            if (isValid)
                break

        }
    }
    sIsValidInstall = isValid
    return isValid
}
```

Another possible reason :

The time setting is wrong on the device.

Comment: If it seems like what I got, there is no need for a solution, because the app was modified and thus it's not the same app anymore, as it can have its own bugs that you can't fix and shouldn't even care about it.

Comment: I do face this issue while using debug builds though. The app is relying on React Native, and accessing Admob through a native bridge. That may have an impact.

Comment: @gbero Can you reproduce it? If so, report to Google/Admob.

Comment: @gbero Also check that the device is on correct time settings.

Comment: I have an app with a lot of thousand of daily users. This happens on about 30-40% of ad requests from the app, and therefore also on the revenues. I have verified that the app is not tampered and it is downloaded from the google play store and verified that a few users had an adblock. I think that this problem is related to webview, but I can't figure it out. I don't use Javascript engine, but admob yes, in its banner and interstitial.

Comment: @PhantomLord When you use banner ads, they use WebView. You can see it by using layout inspector tool in the IDE, or an app like "Developer Assistant". I don't know if interstitial ads use it though. Anyway, to reduce WebView-related issues, you can switch to native ads instead (and maybe have banner ads as fallback if you wish). They should be much more reliable, but they require a lot of work, sadly.

Comment: @PhantomLord I have the same problem as you. We have thousands of users daily and it's affecting revenue, and no, the users don't use VPN or Adblocker. It's something else. Have you figured it out?

Comment: ok, I have implemented native ads instead of my classic banner and interstitial. The result in 6 days? revenue are dropped by up to 20% and "Unable to obtain a JavascriptEngine" error increased. Ad validator says it is all correct. Interstitials are the most affected because it does not exist in native format, I have to implement a "big banner" (full-screen)

Comment: @PhantomLord You got JavascriptEngine issue still, even though you use only native ads? Maybe you should add to Crashlytics a clue (in the form of logs) which ads you tried to load, and on which phase each one reached, including errors. Also maybe use this before calling MobileAds.initialize : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61748345/878126

Comment: No one of my apps is connected to firebase neither crashlitics. I have developed my custom Log library, it is affordable from many years. The apps didn't crash. The error "javascript.." is captured in the event onAdFailedToLoad and reports that Domain: com.google.android.gms.ads Message: Unable to obtain a JavascriptEngine. Code: 0 ResponseInfo: { "Response ID": "null", "Mediation Adapter Class Name": "", "Adapter Responses": [], "Response Extras": {} }. I call MobileAds.initialize at the app startup and after the call to UMP

Comment: Also, all the relevant logs (for debugging purposes) are uploaded (anonymously) to a webserver

Comment: @PhantomLord It doesn't matter which solution you are using to report crashes and if they are even real crashes of the app. Just report them about this case with logs to give you clues of what's going on. You also didn't answer the question about using only native ads. It doesn't make sense that native ads would have this, because JavaScript shouldn't be needed here as there is no WebView.

Comment: Update: I have collected all my statistics and @androiddeveloper, you are right, native ads does not contain any webwiew. All the errors I see are coming from a lot of device with an adblocker. But I cannot understand the large drop in revenues

Comment: @PhantomLord Wait how do you know there is an ad blocker? As for the drop in revenues, could it be related to the recent GDPR ad-consent matter?

Comment: I have devloped a simple ping-tester towards admob.com, doubleclick.com and to countercheck towards google.com with fetching the result; I check if the ping resolves correctly. When the first two resolve to 127.0.0.1 and the third resolves correcrly then   an adblocker is present at 99%.

Comment: @PhantomLord I see. About the revenues, again, could it be because of GDPR ad-consent ?

Comment: How can I see it?

Comment: @PhantomLord You can add Analytics. The most common error code is of no-fill because of this matter. Together with checking if it's GDPR, you can see how much you are affected. And if you haven't handled ad-consent, it might be the reason because Admob probably will show it on its own. There are 2 links that I've found useful for handling data of ad-consent: https://github.com/bocops/UMP-workarounds , https://stackoverflow.com/a/68310602/878126